# Get local cvs comment history when committing file/s in emacs

Tags: emacs, cvs, elisp

I often commit files with similar cvs comment but not in a single operation.  I would like to able to bring up previous comments I've used in a previous commit when I am in the process of writing a comment in emacs.  Meaning, from within the *VC-log* buffer.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-p</kbd>, aka

```
M-x log-edit-previous-comment
```

Though this requires that your Emacs is still the same process, so if you're starting a new Emacs for each commit, this won't work.  To enable that, try either

- committing from Emacs (see [Version Control](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html) info pages, <kbd>C-x v v</kbd> to start)
- using [EmacsClient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) (set the EDITOR (or CVSEDITOR) environment variables)